# How to extract pairs from a dictionary into a new smaller one?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a big dictionary but i only need to use some of the data from it. How can i extract only the pairs that i want and build a new one with the selected data?

```py
{'index': 325, 'name': 'Zombie', 'size': 'Medium', 'type': 'undead' ... }
```

Let's say i only wanted `name` and `type` from this dictionary like so:

```py
{'name': 'Zombie', 'type': 'undead'}
```

How would i go about doing this? I could remove the elements i don't need using `del d[key]` but that seems very inefficient, and won't be reliable if more data gets added later.

The reason i want to make a smaller dictionary is so i can load the data directly into my class like this

```py
Entity(**index[enemy_id])
```

But it won't work if there is more data than the class can hold.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No need to iterate the entire dictionary, just filter out the keys you want:

```
>>> d = {'index': 325, 'name': 'Zombie', 'size': 'Medium', 'type': 'undead'}
>>> keys = ['name', 'type']
>>> {key: d.get(key) for key in keys}
{'name': 'Zombie', 'type': 'undead'}
```

Using `dict.get()` here also prevents `KeyError` from being raised if a key doesn't exist, and just returns `None` instead.

If you want to *ignore* keys that don't exist in `d`, then you can do this:

```
{key: d[key] for key in keys if key in d}
```

Comment: This probably should be the accepted answer, although I don't know about speed for this

Comment: Slower than my method, alas :( It's so clean, I love it!

Comment: I know it's not related to my question per say. but this solution compared to @charly makes fields that doesn't exist `None` instead of ignoring them. which is what i want in this situation. as i've defined defaults for my class.
Is there a way to change this in such a way that it doesn't build `{'type': None}` from `d.get(key)`? (if the key doesn't exist, ignore it).

Comment: @MtotheM Updated answer to include solution that ignores non existent keys

Comment: Nice answer, and quick too. I wonder if that's because it's iterating through the view of the dictionary...@RoadRunner does `key in d` match for keys or values or items?

Comment: @PeptideWitch Cheers :), `key in d` checks if the key exists in `d`, doesn't include values.

Answer (score 4):

Welcome to stack overflow!

I've got more efficient answer. If you know that you only want these 2 items from the dict, and the dictionary is large, it's worthwhile bypassing the dictionary iteration and just making a new dictionary using your keys:

```
old_dict =  {'index': 325, 'name': 'Zombie', 'size': 'Medium', 'type': 'undead'}
new_dict = {'name': old_dict['name'], 'type': old_dict['type']}
```

Comparing my method to the currently accepted answer, my method performs in the nanosecond range vs the millisecond range (a performance difference of 1 million times)

[image]

**EDIT:**

If you have a large list if items you want to drag out:

```
find_these_items = [1, 5, 10, 20]
new_dict = {}
for item in find_these_items:
    new_dict[item] = old_dict[item]
```

Efficiency is still maintained (in the 500ns vs 6.3ms range now).

**EDIT2: Comparing against road runner's method (method3)**

[image]

Comment: This is the solution i came up with at first too. but it seems very tedious as you have to manually type all the keys and value indexes that you need. even in a smaller dictionary with 50 items. this would take a long time and be prone for errors.

Comment: That's fair - if you wanted a large number of entries, we'd need to think of a smarter way to construct the new dictionary without typing out every item manually. As it stands, though, for this question specifically, where only 2 entries are required, I still believe iteration to be unnecessary.

Comment: I can have a go at making a generator for the dictionary. Let me think...

Answer (score 2):

You can create a new dictionary which holds only the element you need, and ignore or delete the old one

```
current_dict = {'index': 325, 'name': 'Zombie', 'size': 'Medium', 'type': 'undead'}
wanted = ['name', 'type']
new_dict = {k: v for k, v in current_dict.items() if k in wanted}
```

Comment: That's great. was looking for something exactly like this.

Comment: I think that for OP's purposes, iterating through the entire dictionary is unnecessary and much much slower than accessing the specific entries required. Please see my answer for details.

Comment: actually, why make wanted a set ?